# Not sure how to fix XML passing error

Tags: java, android, xml

I am knew to Android app development and I was following the tutorial on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Weight (the offical android website. I'm trying to run my code and I think I have copied it exactly as shown with regards to how the tutorial presents it. However I keep getting an error regarding "error passing xml not well formed (invalid token). I would assume this means I have made a small typo somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nothing seems wrong with your xml. Do you have edit_message and button_send strings under your strings.xml file?

Comment: @aegean I seem to have figured it out. I didn't save the file with button_send in it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I did not save the string file with edit_message. This seems to have cleared up the error. Sorry for posting such a silly question.